# SASS vs LESS - for making WordPress theme which one is better?

Tags: css, wordpress, sass, less

Saas and less - two css predecessor,

I am planning to use one of them in my next wordpress theme, Which one should i choose as specially for wordpress theme structure?

With use of [Bones theme](http://themble.com/bones/) which is start up theme for wordpress with sass and less enable,

Syntactically both are almost same. then What is main difference between sass and less?

Answer (score 1):

Confused? Both LESS and SCSS has lot of features that minify CSS and save a huge time.  Less will work on both client side and Server side. SCSS will only work on Server side.

If you are doing a small project, say a Static WebPages or HTML,  I suggest you to use LESS. Because Less takes only few minutes to setup and start.  SCSS need more effort and time to setup (mainly Windows).

If you have a large project and having Big Development, I suggest you to use SCSS because most of the programmers suggest it.

Answer (score 1):

Both the CSS Preprocessors have their own importance.

I suggest you to [READ THIS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/09/an-introduction-to-less-and-comparison-to-sass/) for complete clarity and then you can decide what you want to choose for your project.

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between SASS/SCSS and all other preprocessors is that SASS has a large ecosystem of [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) extensions.

Compass extensions are like libraries of code for all purposes: grid systems, media query tools, styling, math and color functions, resets/normalizations, prefixes... Anything you need.

With LESS or Stylus, you'll have to reinvent the wheel over and over again.

See [Singularity](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity#readme), [Breakpoint](http://breakpoint-sass.com/), [Breakpoint Slicer](https://github.com/lolmaus/breakpoint-slicer#readme), [Toolkit](https://github.com/Team-Sass/toolkit#readme) Compass extensions and this article: [25 Essential Sass and Compass Tools](http://mashable.com/2013/06/11/sass-compass-tools/).

You can use [SassBin.com](http://blog.sassbin.com/post/51720862211/introducing-sassbin) to fiddle with Compass extensions.